# Php работа с массивами

Tags: php

Есть в БД таблица на 300мб, при экспорте этой таблицы в формат php массива, получается файл с массивом такого же размера. Работать с ним через php не вариант.

Если сделать обычный sql запросом с выбору ой всех полей эз этой таблицы, и получить их в виде массива через mysql_fetch_ array, в итоге я получу массив с 2-мы значениями для каждого поля, в виде  в виде ключ => значение.

Первое ключ является названием поля таблицы, а второе просто числовые значение.

А при экспорте таблицы только одно значение для каждого поля.

Почему с массивом который возвращает mysql_fetch_array легче работать и не вызодят ошибки что не хватает памяти и т.д.?

Comment: "Работать с ним через php не вариант" - спорное утверждение. Если вы загружаете весь файл в память, то вы явно делаете что-то не так. Организуйте потоковую обработку. Загружайте по одной строке и экспортируйте в файл не в виде массива PHP (кстати как именно вы это делали?) а, например, в XML или CSV

Answer (score 3):

Потому что `mysql_fetch_array` выбирает в массив всего одну строку из ответа сервера за раз, а не загружает в массив все 300 метров.

-- ИО КО